# PHP MSQL server syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I get this error when trying to get this details page for a project to work. Its for school and I dont really understand PHP that well yet.
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Here is the code for that page.

```html
<?php
    require_once('connection.php');
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
    $recordID = $_GET['recordID'];
    $query_Shoe_Details = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Shoe_Brand = $recordID";
    $Shoe_Details = mysqli_query($conn, $query_Shoe_Details) or die(mysqli_error(($conn)));
    $row_Shoe_Details= mysqli_fetch_assoc($Shoe_Details);
    $totalRows_Shoe_Details = mysqli_num_rows($Shoe_Details);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>details</title><?php include 'connection.php';?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Product Name: <?php echo $row_Shoe_Details['Product_Name']; ?></p>
        <p><img src=
        "images/%3C?php%20echo%20$row_Shoe_Details['Image_Name'];%20?%3E"></p>
        <p>Description: <?php echo $row_Shoe_Details['Product_Description']; ?></p>
        <p>Price: $<?php echo $row_Shoe_Details['Product_Price']; ?></p><?php
            mysqli_free_result($Shoe_Details);
            ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do a `var_dump($recordID)` before the `mysqli_query` and see the result.

Comment: How would that look code wise? Sorry like I said I am totally new to this

Comment: add `var_dump($_GET['recordID']);` at the 2nd line. then run and see the output. if it is initialised.

Comment: may be your $recordID is empty

Comment: I added it right before the require once line and it says the same error message but added NULL to the front of it.

Comment: I'd suggest echo'ing out to screen the SQL statement and look for obvious errors there - try then running that in a gui ( Heidi, mySQL Query Browser etc ) ~ also, you don't need to include the connection twice on the same page

Comment: what is the data type of Shoe_Brand column ?

Comment: no need this again <?php include 'connection.php';?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your query as, use single quotes

```
 $query_Shoe_Details = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE Shoe_Brand = '$recordID'";
```

Also remove this `<?php include 'connection.php';?>`,  No need to include again

Comment: This worked! I am having other issues with how to word my queries to grab data but at least I am a step closer

Answer (score 0):

```
Pl. prepare connection.php file in followng way like 
$dbHost = '';
$dbUser = '';
$dbPass = '';
$dbName = '';

// setting up the web root and server root for
// this shopping cart application
$con=mysql_connect('','','');
    if(!$con)
    {
        die('connection failed');
    }
    $db=mysql_select_db('',$con);
    if(!$db)
    {
        die('db is not selected');
    }
pass proper value in this syntax save it and in your code remove second line and test then and give feedback
```

Comment: don't suggest user to use mysql_*  is deprecated in upcoming version .try to suggest mysqli_* or PDO